# How to hide label in markLine of series-line in Echarts?

Tags: echarts

How to hide label in markLine of series-line in Echarts? Or how to change label style?

I tried `label: false`, not working.

```
series: [
    markLine: {
        silent: true,
        symbol: false,
        label: false,
        data: [{
            yAxis: 100
        }, {
            yAxis: 400
        }],
        lineStyle: {
            normal: {
                type: "solid",
                color: "red"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be:

```
series: [
    markLine: {
        label: {
            normal: {
                show: false
            }
        }
    }
]
```

`normal` is the style when not *mouse over* or *touch down*. Otherwise, it would be `emphasis`.

Please refer to [doc](http://echarts.baidu.com/option.html#series-line.markLine.label.normal.show).